# Numbered Musical Notation Writing Software

Tags: music

Is there any numbered musical notation writing tool in Linux?

I want to write something like this:

```
 Do = C

 1   1     2   1   |  4  3 . . |  
 Hap-py Birth-day     To You
```

Numbered musical notation: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numbered_musical_notation

Preferably a free and cross platform one.

Comment: What do you want the software to actually do?

Comment: automatically adds space padding on note and lyrics, adds upper line and bottom line, etc..

Comment: I don't know anything about the music software, can Lilypond do what you want? It supports the notation you asked about.

Comment: no Lilypond can't.. see the screenshot, it's really different..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a list of music software maintained at linux-sound.org. It's pretty exhaustive, you might want to poke through that list and see if you can't find what you're looking for:

- http://linux-sound.org/notation.html

#### Lilypond

It looks like Lilypond can do what you want. The notation also goes by the name "Simple Notation" and also "[Ziffersystem](http://www.gameo.org/encyclopedia/contents/Z544ME.html)".

- http://lilypond.org/doc/v2.12/Documentation/user/lilypond-learning/Simple-notation

If you look towards the bottom of the references section of the Wikipedia page you referenced there are links to Lilypond specifically about this notation as well.

#### music.stackexchange.com

After googling a bit more I found this Q&A over on the SE site music.stackexchange.com that asks the same question.

- [Is there a specific name for Sheet music that uses numbers (二胡 Èrhú Sheet Music)?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/4914/is-there-a-specific-name-for-sheet-music-that-uses-numbers-erhu-sheet-music)

This notation is also called [Jianpu](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jianpu). There is an extensive reference to Jianpu here on this blog: [BennyT85Erhu's Blog](http://bennyt85erhu.wordpress.com/jianpu/).

#### musescore

I found this [feature request from 2011 to have JianPu support](http://musescore.org/en/node/12338) added to the application Musescore. There is a list of applications that do support JianPu in a post on that feature request.

It would appear that musescore is working to add this as a feature to their application. It's listed here on the [2013 page of projects](http://musescore.org/en/developers-handbook/google-summer-code/ideas-2013) and has someone assigned to work on it.

> Jianpu notation support in MuseScore
>
> Jianpu notation/Numbered musical notation is widely used in China. A
>   large amount of Chinese music is recorded in Jianpu and most Chinese
>   people are more familiar with Jianpu than standard staff scores. But
>   there are relatively limited software for editing Jianpu and they have
>   obvious disadvantages. In sum, there's a need for high quality Jianpu
>   notation software. For more information: Here.
>
> Difficulty: Hard
>   Skills: C++/Qt
>   Student: Eli Yang
>   Possible mentor: lasconic, Rui Fan (aka Vanferry)

Comment: thanks for the clue.. but i believe "Simple Notation" on Lilypond is not what i want..

Comment: because of your clue, i found one: http://bennyt85erhu.wordpress.com/jianpu/ thanks :3

Comment: See updates, hope they have what you're looking for.

Comment: I found this s/w but it's only for windows: http://www.a1soft.com/smusic/index.htm. You could run it under Wine in Linux, I would guess. Given it's simplicity I'd be surprised if it didn't run under Wine.

Comment: from the screenshot i think it doesn't support lyrics?

Comment: You mean that it doesn't show the lyrics along with the number notations? Yeah based on the screen I'd guess it doesn't. Might be worth a try though, you never know.